# Can I use apps like LADB WiFi ADB or Wi-Fi Debugging without needing a USB cable ever during the process?

Tags: adb, root-access, android-10, motorola, developer-options

I have an old Android tablet that had been rooted but my phone hasn't been rooted....yet.
What I need to understand is if there's a way to use my tablet to perform edits on my phone without EVER needing a USB cable to do so.
LADB requires Android 11 it seems but my phone (Moto E 2020) isn't eligible for any system upgrades and as I mentioned above, the phone isn't rooted. I've already downloaded apks like TWRP, LADB, Wireless Debugging and I've already enabled adb in the dev options.
So is it possible to connect to the phone using the tablet?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. The adb demon on an Android device isn't the same as the one that runs on a Linux, Mac or Windows development machine. The adb client program that is run on a development machine isn't available on Android devices.